# Tkinter taking txt data from another definition of button

Tags: python, button, input, tkinter, definition

My code is looking like this right now:

```
def browse_button():
    ftypes1 = [('file', '*.txt')]
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes1)
    print(filename1)
    with open(filename1) as newfile1:
        file1 = pd.read_table(newfile1, sep=',', names=('A', 'B', 'C'))
        print file1

    return filename1

def file_button():
    abc=browse_button()
    print abc
                  # in this definition i want to work on the input file that  
                    i have imported at start in browse_button definition,but 
                    it doesn't work good
```

i am using this code to run them them

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('title')
    root.geometry("450x150+200+200")
    b1 = Button(root, text='one', font=('arial', 12), command=browse_button)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b6 = Button(root, text='file', font=('arial', 12), command=file_button)
    b6.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Thank You in advice!

Comment: The indentation of the first block is broken

Comment: @Bryan Oakley , corrected, i just copy it in wrong way, but it still doesnt solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you have stated you want to work on the file that you have opened but all you are doing is returning is only the file name.

`return(filename1)` this statement in your `browse_button()` function is only returning the name of the file to `file_button()` and not the data. In result say the file name was `my_file` the `print abc` will result in: `my_file`

Where you create the variable `filename1` all you are doing is getting the file name. If you are trying to work with the content of the file then you need to return `file1` from your `with open` statement instead.

Update:

I have created a similar code that opens a text file I created and will print out its content using the 2nd function.

EDIT: I added your buttons to my answer so you can see how it should all look together.

```
# Python 3 imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Python 2 imports
# from Tkinter import *
# from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def browse_button():
    ftypes1 = [('file', '*.txt')]
    filename1 =  askopenfilename(filetypes = ftypes1)
    with open(filename1) as newfile1:
        file1 = newfile1.read()
        print (file1)

    return filename1

def file_button():
    abc=browse_button()
    print (abc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('title')
    root.geometry("450x150+200+200")
    b1 = Button(root, text='one', font=('arial', 12), command=browse_button)
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b6 = Button(root, text='file', font=('arial', 12), command=file_button)
    b6.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    root.mainloop()
```

Result:

```
Content of my_file!
```

Comment: its seems to be same as i wrote already, then i am adding `abc=openFile()` to `def WortkWithFile()` when i am runing the script the window automaticly opens, i dont know why, it should wait till i push the button ;/

Comment: @Pawe: If you copied my code there is `workWithFile()` that calls the function when the program starts. You can remove that. I only used it for an example.

Comment: and its not the same. I am returning the content of the file. In the code you wrote you are trying to return the filename itself.

Comment: @Pawe: I updated my answer to include the buttons as well so you can see how it should look all together.

Comment: Doing a `return` in a function attached to a button is pointless. The code that called the function (ie: mainloop) ignores any data that is returned. Your example reads the file and then just throws the data away.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: What do you mean by ignore? It works for me as expected.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: I apologize. I wasn't clear. In the button that directly calls `browse_button`, the data that is read from the file will be ignored. You are correct, though, that the "File" button will be able to use that data.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I don't understand It is working as expected. It prints the content of the file just fine.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: try clicking the "one" button. You'll see that the data that is real will be ignored.

Comment: The example was to show the result of pressing the file button. As the OP was having problems with the file button. That is why my answer is only working for the file button.

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech , its not doing well in my case, if i will add `with open("my_file","r")` i need to set the path , and thats not the point because i want to choose the file which i will working on. also when i am doing like you wrote its doesnt works, and window is opening automaticly

Comment: @Pawe: After reading all the comments and looking at your question a few more times I think I understand what you need. I will work on an updated answer.

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech i found the mistake, it was `command=file_button())` should be `command=file_button)` because of this button was automaticly runed. Thanks

Comment: @Pawe: That was not in your original question. you had it formatted as `command=file_button` in your question so I thought that was what you were using.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: Sorry for the confusion Some of your comments came in out of order for me. I have corrected my answer to include all functionality.

Comment: @Sierra Mountain Tech, i have one more question, if its necessary please let me know, and i will open a new topic. I know that `file_button()` is doing same thing as `browse_button()` but how can i get only the data opened in `browse_button() def` ??